# How to make gerrit slave read only?

Tags: git, gerrit

I need little help if anybody is aware of this issue.

I am trying to make gerrit slave for a master. I was able to replicate the repositories onto the slave server. But I have few doubts.

1. How to configure the replica server for access by authorized users?
2. What the limitations of replica server access control are (e.g. is it read only?)
   If its not read only then how to make it read only.

Here is my `replication.config` file.

```
[remote "pubmirror"]

url = ssh://< Slave_User >@< Slave_User_ip >/path/to/repo/${name}.git

replicationDelay = 1
```

I'm hoping someone can make me understand with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `container.slave` option in etc/gerrit.config to true (see [documentation](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8/config-gerrit.html)) will enable slave mode (by passing `--slave` to the [Gerrit daemon](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8/pgm-daemon.html)), which makes the server read-only and disables the HTTP server

Apart from that the regular rules for configuring e.g. access control and authentication apply.

Comment: Is there any way to authorize selected users to directly push into the slave? @Magnus

Comment: No, unless they bypass Gerrit and push straight into the gits via the file system. But why would you want to do that? Getting the master and the slaves out of sync is a bad idea, and since one usually sets up the master to forcefully push changes to the slaves, any changes made on the slaves would be deleted in the next round of replication from the master.

Answer (score 1):

the --slave unfortunately doesn't provide Web UI for viewing the reviews. One way to workaround it is  to run gerrit in normal mode but

a) change the gerrit.config to restrict receive.allowGroup to e.g. only administrators then none (except administrators) can push to gerrit git repositories

b) put gerrit httpd behind an apache proxy and use mod_rewrite to restrict to set of read only requests. I basically allow only GET, HEAD and POST for /login, /gerrit_ui/rpc/ChangeDetailService and /gerrit_ui/rpc/PatchDetailService

It works quite well for us with single gerrit master and multi readonly replica in different data centers

Comment: Agree on the '--slave' switch does not work in all scenarios.. If you are in situation that you can only allow http protocol on the read only mirrors, the '--slave' won't work for you.  
Thanks for the receive.allowGroup tip!